# Stored procedure to populate a table with more than 100 data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm a novice in SQL and I'm looking for an effective way to insert a lot of data (600 records exactly) into a database table. The data is split into 4 columns.

So far I was thinking to do it like that

```
insert into myTable(col1, col2, col3, col4)
values('value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3', 'value 4')
```

But entering 600 records like that is no fun. How could I speed up adding values to a table?

Comment: If your data is already in digital format, you can do a script (php, excel formula,... ) who generate you insert statement. After you copy/past into your database manager (phpMyAdmin, Toad, SQL Developper, ...)

Comment: @Camille - That seems like a nice idea. Its worth a try.                                     underscore_d - Sorry, I updated the heading

Comment: If it's SQL-Server, and using SSMS, my go-to here would be the data import wizard. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/start-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: how does your input looks like ? A cvs file or something ? Can you post an example

Comment: @GuidoG - No its a .txt file. But im going to put it to excel file and then import the data to sql

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+import+a+text+file+into+sql+server+table&oq=how+to+import+a+text+file+into+sql+server&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.8359j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: You can use an online generator that creates a SQL script based on your text file, such as http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a one-time task, then I usually load the data into a spreadsheet, create a simple formula, copy this formula to all the lines, then copy-paste a result to the SQL script - and it's done. No matter if it is 600 or 1 million records, the work takes only a few minutes.
Simple example - the spreadsheet looks like this:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   A    |   B    |   C    |   D    |                                          E                                           |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| col1   | col2   | col3   | col4   | Formula                                                                              |
| val 1  | val 21 | val 1  | val 21 | ="INSERT INTO table( col1, col2, col3) VALUES( '"&A2&"','"&B2&"','"&C2&"','"&D2&"');" |
| val 2  | val 22 | val 2  | val 22 |                                                                                      |
| val 3  | val 23 | val 3  | val 23 |                                                                                      |
| val 4  | val 24 | val 4  | val 24 |                                                                                      |
| val 5  | val 25 | val 5  | val 25 |                                                                                      |
| val 6  | val 26 | val 6  | val 26 |                                                                                      |
| val 7  | val 27 | val 7  | val 27 |                                                                                      |
| val 8  | val 28 | val 8  | val 28 |                                                                                      |
| val 9  | val 29 | val 9  | val 29 |                                                                                      |
| val 10 | val 30 | val 10 | val 30 |                                                                                      |
| val 11 | val 31 | val 11 | val 31 |                                                                                      |
| val 12 | val 32 | val 12 | val 32 |                                                                                      |
| val 13 | val 33 | val 13 | val 33 | 
.....
.....
.....
```

The formula in column E is:

```
="INSERT INTO table( col1, col2, col3) VALUES( '"&A2&"','"&B2&"','"&C2&"','"&D2&"');"
```

This formula evaluates to a result like this:

```
INSERT INTO table( col1, col2, col3) VALUES( 'val 1','val 21','val 1','val 21');
```

If you copy the formula in column E into cells for all rows you will get a ready-to-run script, just copy a content of column E to the clipboard and paste it to a text file:

```
INSERT INTO table( col1, col2, col3) VALUES( 'val 1','val 21','val 1','val 21');
INSERT INTO table( col1, col2, col3) VALUES( 'val 2','val 22','val 2','val 22');
INSERT INTO table( col1, col2, col3) VALUES( 'val 3','val 23','val 3','val 23');
INSERT INTO table( col1, col2, col3) VALUES( 'val 4','val 24','val 4','val 24');
INSERT INTO table( col1, col2, col3) VALUES( 'val 5','val 25','val 5','val 25');
INSERT INTO table( col1, col2, col3) VALUES( 'val 6','val 26','val 6','val 26');
INSERT INTO table( col1, col2, col3) VALUES( 'val 7','val 27','val 7','val 27');
INSERT INTO table( col1, col2, col3) VALUES( 'val 8','val 28','val 8','val 28');
INSERT INTO table( col1, col2, col3) VALUES( 'val 9','val 29','val 9','val 29');
INSERT INTO table( col1, col2, col3) VALUES( 'val 10','val 30','val 10','val 30');
INSERT INTO table( col1, col2, col3) VALUES( 'val 11','val 31','val 11','val 31');
INSERT INTO table( col1, col2, col3) VALUES( 'val 12','val 32','val 12','val 32');
INSERT INTO table( col1, col2, col3) VALUES( 'val 13','val 33','val 13','val 33');
INSERT INTO table( col1, col2, col3) VALUES( 'val 14','val 34','val 14','val 34');
INSERT INTO table( col1, col2, col3) VALUES( 'val 15','val 35','val 15','val 35');
INSERT INTO table( col1, col2, col3) VALUES( 'val 16','val 36','val 16','val 36');
...
...
...
```

Comment: Excellent!, exactly what I was looking for!. Thanks